# multi level hierarchical clustering selection

Tags: cluster-analysis, mathematical-optimization, bin-packing, hierarchical-clustering

I have hierarchical clustering tree (using linkage). Each cluster has its own level in the dendrogram which corresponds to the cost of that cluster. I have budget for n1 clusters with cost c1, n2 clusters with cost c2, and n3 clusters with cost c3. The question is to select which cluster using the budget to cover all original items. and c1>c2>c3. Clusters with cost c1 can be used for c2 or c3 clusters obviously.

For only one budget category, the solution is trivial: just start from the root and in each subtree when we go below c1 add it. If n1 categories are finished before subtrees there is no solution.

For two categories it is also simple. Find all candidates for c1 cost. Label them with the number of c2 sub-clusters and sort them descendingly. Select the c1 categories with maximum label. Then select c2 clusters.

But the problem is complex for more than 2 categories as sorting for c2 categories does not necessarily keeps track of c3 budget.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: suppose this graph: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dendrogram.gif we have budget for 2 clusters with cost at most 0.5, and 2 clusters with cost at most 0.4 . So we must select green and red clusters as 0.5 level and blue and purple for 0.4 category